# Match Text Within Parenthesis Multiple Times

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have text like this:

```
<p>Joe likes <ul><li>pizza</li>, <li>burgers</li>, and <li>fries</li></ul></p>
```

I want to use a single regex to extract all of the text between the `<li>`/list tags using python.

```
regexp = <p>.+?(<li>.+?</li>).+?</p>
```

This only returns the first item in the list surrounded by the `<li>`/list tags:

```
<li>pizza</li>
```

Is there a way for me to grab all of the items between the `<li>`/list tags so my output would look like:

```
<li>pizza</li><li>burgers</li><li>fries</li>
```

Comment: I would suggest using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import re

source = '<p>Joe likes <ul><li>pizza</li>, <li>burgers</li>, and <li>fries</li></ul></p>'
res = ''.join(re.findall('<li>[^<]*</li>', source))
# <li>pizza</li><li>burgers</li><li>fries</li>
```

Comment: Merig.  Thank you.  Great answer.  But, for my very specific purposes, that won't solve my problem.  Any way to get the text between the li tags out using regex alone (not resorting to other python functions)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already extracted the example string you state you can do:

```
import re
s = "<p>Joe likes <ul><li>pizza</li>, <li>burgers</li>, and <li>fries</li></ul></p>"
re.findall("<li>.+?</li>", s)

Output:
['<li>pizza</li>', '<li>burgers</li>', '<li>fries</li>']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the `<p>` tags ?

```
import re

source = '<p>Joe likes <ul><li>pizza</li>, <li>burgers</li>, and <li>fries</li></ul></p>'

m = re.findall('(<li>.+?</li>)',source)
print m
```

returns want you want.

**Edit**

If you only want text that is between `<p>` tags you can do it in two steps :

```
import re

source = '<p>Joe likes <ul><li>pizza</li>, <li>burgers</li>, and <li>fries</li></ul></p> and also <li>coke</li>'

ss = re.findall('<p>(.+?)</p>',source)

for s in ss:
    m = re.findall('(<li>.+?</li>)',s)
    print m
```

Comment: Hey Hugo.  <p> tags are necessary because I am assuming that this sentence is part of a much larger page with many <li>.  The <p> tag is just an example tag that would illustrate how I might isolate the specific sentence I am trying to extract info from.

Comment: Am looking for a way to do this without the "findall,"  I would like to get all the text out as a single match using findone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex with re.findall()

To get text: `<li>([^<]*)</li>` , To get tags: `<li>[^<]*</li>`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<p>Joe likes <ul><li>pizza</li>, <li>burgers</li>, and <li>fries</li></ul></p>"
>>> text=re.findall("<li>([^<]*)</li>", s)
>>> tag=re.findall("<li>[^<]*</li>", s)
>>> text
['pizza', 'burgers', 'fries']
>>> tag
['<li>pizza</li>', '<li>burgers</li>', '<li>fries</li>']
>>>
```